# Scroll to div not working when Product Detail page have Product Gallery

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

Scroll top in jquery not working.

I am using

- Offers for WooCommerce plugin (Version 1.4.9).
- WooCommerce (Version 3.4.3).
- WordPress (Version 4.9.6).

Offers plugin adding **Make offer button** on the shop page and when we click on that it redirects to Offers tab of the product.

For that we have used **scrollTop** function in js file.
Here is the code.

```
var targetTab = $(".tab_custom_ofwc_offer_tab");
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $(targetTab).offset().top - '100'
}, 'fast');
```

**While WooCommerce Product page have Product Gallery it is not scroll to that particular div.**
Please see the Image  : https://www.screencast.com/t/BIH5qkKU

**Here is the video link for the issue : https://screenpresso.com/=V3NRf**

Click to watch the video of how the above things are happening.

Any information on this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: can you try wrapping it inside setTimeout with 0 delay? i.e wait until the elements to be rendered then do scrolling

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem in your code,

try this

```
var targetTab = $(".tab_custom_ofwc_offer_tab");
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(targetTab).offset().top - '100'
    }, 'fast');
```

Comment: Nope, Code wasn't structured in the question , I tried adding your code but no luck because we have same code.

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing the element twice from jQuery, **remove** jQuery from this variable ***$(****targetTab****)*** :

```
var targetTab = $(".tab_custom_ofwc_offer_tab");
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: targetTab.offset().top - '100'
}, 'fast');
```